# Counting items in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, .net-3.5, multidimensional-array

If I have the following array:

```
    Dim Array(4, 10) As String
    Array(0, 0) = "100"
    Array(0, 1) = "200"
    Array(1, 0) = "300"
    Array(1, 1) = "400"
    Array(1, 2) = "500"
    Array(1, 3) = "600"
```

How do I get the following count:

```
0 = 2
1 = 4
```

Comment: Removed ASP.NET tag: there is nothing about ASP.NET here.

Comment: This array is for an asp.net website, so it has everything to do with asp.net.

Comment: No, really, this *question* has nothing to do with ASP.NET, as evidenced by the fact that the whole question would work sit perfectly well in a console application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to count the number of `non-Nothing` values in each dimension of the array.  The following function will allow you to do that

```
Public Function CountNonNothing(ByVal data As String(,), ByVal index As Integer) As Integer
    Dim count = 0
    For j = 0 To data.GetLength(1) - 1
        If data(index, j) IsNot Nothing Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return count
End Function
```

And it can be invoked like so

```
Dim count1 = CountNonNothing(Array, 0)
Dim count2 = CountNonNothing(Array, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I used a C# to VB converter so hopefully the VB syntax is correct.

I made a simple extension method that makes this pretty easy:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Extensions
Private Sub New()
End Sub
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function GetNonNullItems(Of T)(array As T(,), index As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    For i As Integer = 0 To array.GetLength(index) - 1
        If array(index, i) IsNot Nothing Then
            yield Return array(index, i)
        End If
    Next
End Function
End Class
```

Then to use it:

```
Dim Array As String(,) = New String(4, 10) {}
Array(0, 0) = "100"
Array(0, 1) = "200"
Array(1, 0) = "300"
Array(1, 1) = "400"
Array(1, 2) = "500"
Array(1, 3) = "600"

Dim countArray0 As Integer = Array.GetNonNullItems(0).Count()
Dim countArray1 As Integer = Array.GetNonNullItems(1).Count()
```

The extension method will give you back all non null items found for a given index.  From that you can get the count, filter, query, or use them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Converted from c# but it could be something like this.

```
Dim count As Integer() = New Integer(Array.GetLength(0) - 1) {}
For i As Integer = 0 To Array.GetLength(0) - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To Array.GetLength(1) - 1
        If Array(i, j) IsNot Nothing Then
            count(i) += 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Now count of `0's` would be in `count(0)`, count of `1's` would be in `count(1)`, so on...